# How to connect my AppRunner instance to RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I've configured RDS with the suggested defaults and no public access.

Then I put my AppRunner instance in the same security group as RDS by creating a VPC connector. I can see the same VPC and subnets listed on both sides yet I somehow don't have a connection to RDS still (my AppRunner instance can't connect). What am I doing wrong? Isn't it enough to put them in the same security group and VPC?